# name the animated movie showing earth from an alien point of view in which cars are seen as the dominant life form

Tags: identify-this-movie

What is the name of the animated short film (pre 1985) that shows an alien's view of earth and they think cars are the main life form?

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are talking about the 1966 animated short film, "[What on Earth!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_on_Earth!)". It's presented as a mockumentary by the Film Board of Mars (Actually the National Film Board of Canada), and mistakes cars as the dominant life form on Earth.

It was nominated for an Academy Award, and can be seen on the [NFB website](https://www.nfb.ca/film/what_on_earth).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I thought maybe it was NFB and old when I saw it in '85.  I loved it and want to see it again so I really appreciate you telling me where I can find it.:-)